# How can I get `facet_wrap` plot for the data.frame named with unexpected long pattern?

Tags: r, regex, ggplot2

I have data.frame list where its column named with rather complicated string, and that need to be plotted by using `facet_wrap`. I intend to manipulate the this complicated string and plot in `facet_grid`. I got some idea to split the string by using `\n`, but in resulted plot, my desired label still is not fully displayed. Can anyone give me some idea how to plot the data.frame if label the column named with long character? How can I achieve my desired plot ?

reproducible data.frame :

```
myList <- list(
    wmTncofSydhTfbsK90cmxcgMnP30SxEAlnTest1.saved=
        data.frame(GRP=c("up","up","down"), Name=rep("wmTncofSydhTfbsK90cmxcgMnP30SxEAlnTest1", 3),
                   v1=c(2,7,9)),
    wmTncofSydhTfbsK90cmxcgMnP30SxEAlnTest2.saved=
        data.frame(GRP=c("up","down","up","down"), Name=rep("wmTncofSydhTfbsK90cmxcgMnP30SxEAlnTest2", 4),
                   v1=c(13,8,11,3))
)
```

This is my imaginative desired plot :

[image]

How can I get this desired plot ? How can I plot the data.frame if it named with unexpected long character ? Thanks in advance

**Edit** :
threshold for getting `up`, `down`group, we can set threshold `threshold >9`for `up`; otherwise `down`. sorry for this missing point.

but how can I continue this code where I am trying to manipulate that long string column in data ? Can anyone point me how to proceed my approach and produce my desired plot ?

Comment: Have you tried manuall adding a `\n` character in the string?

Comment: @AlexR Yes, I tried `\n`, perhaps I did something wrong when I prepare plot data. I tried to get single data.frame first, then manipulate that long string in its column, then plot them. But I can't produce my desired plot. Any idea please ? Thanks :)

Comment: Could you post some C&P-able code so I can get to exactly what your `data.frame` looks like? I don't have any problem with an added `\n`. It creates a line break just as expected and centers both parts.

Comment: not sure if i get you correctly - but wouldn't the call to `facet_wrap( ~ Name)` get you what you want - independent of what complicated strings are in the `Name` variable. Also - you would need to put everything in one data frame first.

Comment: @davidski The problem is croping of long captions in the facets.

Comment: @Jerry.Shad The column `upDown` needs to be `mutate()`'d into the posted code...

Comment: @Jerry.Shad I've come up with a MWE for your problem. I think you should be able to adapt the code to your situation fairly easily.

Comment: @AlexR I think your solution is bit of hard to follow. My approach, subset the column has long string, then by using `\n` to split for making plot data, then produce plot. Is that possible to make your answer easier ? Thank you

Comment: How does your data match the plot? you have only one "down" for the "Test1"? Your data and what you want are very unclear IMO.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I framed desired plot based on my thought, so it could be something else (perhaps I made mistake when representing data in the plot). But, the issue is, `Name` column goes to top as `label`. Could you produce your thought please? Thank you very much

Comment: @Jerry.Shad Have you tried my method of dealing with the long strings yet? It should solve your problem easily...

Comment: @AlexR I just solved the problem on my own. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some sample code to correct the problem by splitting the column `A` into lines of at most 26 characters:

```
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(A = c(paste(rep(LETTERS, 3), collapse = ""), paste(rep(letters, 3), collapse = "")), B = 3)
ggplot(df, aes(x = B)) + facet_wrap(~A) + geom_bar()
while(any(str_detect(df$A, "(?<=(^|\\n))[\\n]{26}(?=[^\\n])"))) {
  df %<>% mutate(A = str_replace(A, "(?<=(^|\\n))[\\n]{26}(?=[^\\n])", "\\0\n"))
}
ggplot(df, aes(x = B)) + facet_wrap(~A) + geom_bar()
```

The core is repeatedly replacing the regex pattern `(?<=(^|\n))[^\n]{26}(?=[^\\n])` wich matches a 26-character (chose at your own discretion) length substring wich is not immediately succeeded by a newline and is preceeded by the beginning of the string or by a newline.

I suggest stepping through the `while` loop to understand how the regex works.